# Should I return a method call like console.log()?

Tags: javascript, return

Good day everyone. I haven't found any research or articles regarding this. Maybe I was using the wrong search terms. but my question was lets say for example that I am writing a small utility library in JavaScript for myself and I want to include 2 small functions `out(arg)` and `outln(arg)`. My question is should i simply call `console.log()` or `return console.log()`.
I've seen it done both ways but never saw a reason to return a method call. I was wondering which way is better or does it make a difference at all?

EX.

```
// This way:

var lib = {
    out: function(args){
        console.log(args);
    },
    outln: function(args){
        console.log(args + "\n");
    }
};

// Or this way?

var lib = {
    out: function(args){
        return console.log(args);
    },
    outln: function(args){
        return console.log(args + "\n");
    }
};
```

Comment: Why would you want to return something that you don't use? Generally the return from a function is something that you wish to use elsewhere. If you are not going to use it, don't return it p.s. This may not work the same way across all browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Comment: Hey I'm sorry for the late reply...college...but I really appreciate the feedback and the link. I never really thought about it that way I guess but that is logical and makes total sense. There is no need to return something i won't use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any use for the return value from `console.log` (which is always `undefined` anyway iirc ) ? You might plan to override `log` or create your own `console` object, though (not recommended).

More important, check for the presence of the console  object and the log  method, as some user agents have been known not to provide them:

```
var lib = {
    out: function(args) {
             if (console && console.log) {
                 console.log(args);
             }
         },
    outln: function(args) {
               if (console && console.log) {
                   console.log(args+"\n");
               }
         }
}
```

Promoting robustness, test this way instead of once during your lib's initialization and setting a global ( you might even consider to add the test to your lib if you have a use case, eg. users/code tampering with the console object ).

Comment: Cool thanks for the response. Sorry for the late reply been writing a paper for school. I'll do that for sure. i appreciate it much.